# If $A^n$ is similar to $B^n$ for non-nilpotent real metrices A and B, is A similar to B?

Tags: matrices, similar-matrices

let $A,B$ be real non-nilpotent metrices, such that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ for which -

$A^n = P^{-1} B^n P$

holds.

does there always exist an invertible matrix $M$ such that -

$A = M^{-1}BM$ ?

if the answer is yes, does it change if the matrices $A,B$ are over $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Sure. For $n=1$ we obtain that $A$ and $B$ are similar by assumption. Or do you mean, only for some $n$?

Comment: No, e.g. take any reflection as $A$, and $B=I$, $n=2$.

Comment: @Berci , right, thanks!